# Problem in adding pictures in Javascript function in WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm facing a problem to show an image in javascript file in a WordPress theme,
I tried to use `<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri());?>`
 but it doesn't work in JS file,

so this line doesn't work because it is in JS file:

```
   document.getElementById("women-eyes1").src="<?php echo 
   esc_url(get_template_directory_uri());?> images/ss1.png";
```

how can I direct to image in js file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use php functions in a js file `file.js`. You can use inline script in your php file like this:

```
// some php file
// output the script
?>
<script>
   document.getElementById("women-eyes1").src="<?php echo 
   esc_url(get_template_directory_uri());?> images/ss1.png";
</script>
<?php // rest of your php
```

or you can use [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and pass the values like this:

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

then use the variable in your js file:

```
<script>
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.some_string);
</script>
```

Comment: so if I want to add the picture with  wp_localize_script how can I do that?